# Fontspec and Symbolic Endnotes with Enotez

Tags: fontspec, enotez

I am writing an article which requires the use of endnotes in general, and that the first endnote be an asterisk rather than a numeral. I am using the enotez package for the endnotes, and it works fine (producing arabic numerals for the notes by default), until I use the \setenotez{counter-format=symbols} to try to change to symbolic footnotes (my intent is to then change back to arabic after the first note). This produces the error:

> ! Argument of @rsbox has an
>   extra }.

This error only occurs if I have both a command setting the font (which I'd obviously like to do, and currently using fontspec for) *and* the command setting the endnote style to symbols. Here is a MWE - or rather, a MNWE. If I remove either of the lines followed by commented notes, it works.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Times New Roman} %The error only occurs with this

\usepackage{enotez}

\begin{document}

\setenotez{counter-format=symbols} %The error only occurs with this

Here be dragons.\endnote{`Here' is undefined.} Where?

There!

\printendnotes

\end{document}
```

I have no idea why these things are interacting like this. Is there an easy fix, or some other tools I could use instead to get a symbolic endnote? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you check if `\renewcommand\thefootnote{\fnsymbol{footnote}}` in combination with a footnote instead of `enotez` throws an error, too?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the behaviour with an up dto date TeX live

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue it describes has been fixed in an up to date distribution.